# Google Sheets trigger writing to cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a trigger or function for a sheet but I want it to run Onchange and populate cells. I already have the trigger to run Onchange but haven't been able to learn how to properly get it to fill cells with information.
This works if I make a cell =sheetnames(), but it won't update if I add or delete a sheet, I have to clear the cell and put in the formula again.

I've only really tried reading over and seeing how people solved similar problems and trying to adapt it. I don't have much experience with code though.

```
function sheetnames() {
var out = new Array()
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )
return out 
}
```

Well, the code runs as expected, but what I desire is that `onchange` it will populate a column with the names of all the sheets currently in the... sheet. I have 2 sheets currently "Primary" as the first, then "SheetNames" as the second.

Comment: What sheet and range do you want it to populate?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Don't use this as a cell function it will populate the first column of the sheet named SheetNames.  Make sure that you don't have two functions with the same name.  So get rid of the old one or change the names some how.

```
function sheetnames() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var osh=ss.getSheetByName('SheetNames');
  var out = [];
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  for (var i=0;i<sheets.length;i++) {
    out.push([sheets[i].getName()] )
  }
  osh.getRange(1,1,out.length,1).setValues(out);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Well it errors when fired by `onchange` but it works how I wanted it to!

Comment: @Lithe You could try using an `onEdit` trigger instead, you can do this by renaming the function to `onEdit(e)` instead of `sheenames`